# Working with 'single file' Vue.js components in Orchard / ASP.NET MVC / Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, vue.js, orchardcms

I have a large website that is hosted in Azure and using Orchard as a CMS.  There are several custom modules we have developed within the Orchard framework that are basically just ASP.NET MVC that play nice inside Orchard.  Nothing too fancy.

Not being a full time web guy (I usually do desktop apps) I am struggling with a few noob problems trying to get my first 'single file' Vue.js component working.  I think my problems stem from some simple syntactical and/or url/filepath problems.  But I've been trying permutations blindly without much luck, so I am hoping someone will point me in the right direction.

To begin, here is my working starting point

My simplified razor (index.cshtml) file:

```
@{

    Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead();

    Style.Include("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css").AtHead();
    Script.Include("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js").AtHead();

    Script.Include("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js").AtHead();
}

<div id="my-vue-app" class="container">

    <h2>This is a simple razor page</h2>

    <div v-for="shop in pizzaShops">
        <p>{{ shop.id }} - {{ shop.name }}</p>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Right now, I am placing the js as a sibling of the view.  Placing the js into -->
<!-- the scripts folder feels disjointed right now.  The paths to the view is --> 
<!-- driven by Orchard naming and filepath conventions.  Being a prototype, I'm not -->
<!-- to hung up on this right now. -->
<script src="~/modules/mymodule/views/myviewfolder/index.js"></script>
```

My simplified Vue app (index.js) file:

```
const pizzaShops = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Pizza The Hut'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Little Geezers'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Pappa Runs'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Tri-ominoes'
    }
];

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-vue-app',
    data: {
        pizzaShops
    }
});
```

When I compile and run the files above, everything works as expected and my view contains
the output you would expect:

```
Better Components! Better Pizza Pizza!

1 - Pizza The Hut
2 - Little Geezers
3 - Pappa Runs
4 - Tri-ominoes
```

Now when I try to introduce my 'single file' Vue component things go off the rails.

Here is my simplified 'single-file' Vue component (pizzashop.vue):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>static content</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
     name: 'pizzaShopComponent'
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

and my updated view (index.cshtml)

```
<div id="my-vue-app" class="container">

    <h2>Better Components! Better Pizza Pizza!</h2>

    <div v-for="shop in pizzaShops">
        <p>{{ shop.id }} - {{ shop.name }}</p>
    </div>

    <pizzaShopComponent v-for="shop in pizzaShops" :shop="shop"></pizzaShopComponent>

</div>
```

Now I *think* all I need to do is connect the dots in my index.js, like this:

```
import pizzaShopComponent from './pizzashop.vue'

const pizzaShops = [
  //ommitted for brevity
];

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-vue-app',
    data: {
        pizzaShops
    },
    components: {
        pizzaShopComponent
    }
});
```

but this results in my ouput changing to:

```
Better Components! Better Pizza Pizza!

{{ shop.id }} - {{ shop.name }}
```

and this console message

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

I tried adding type="module" like this:

```
<script type="module" src="~/modules/mymodule/views/myviewfolder/index.js"></script>
```

Which does fix/suppress the console message but I still have this output:

```
Better Components! Better Pizza Pizza!

{{ shop.id }} - {{ shop.name }}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?  It seems like this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single File vue components require a build tool like webpack to generate a javascript file that you can then use within the browser. They have example templates to help get you started with .vue files: https://github.com/vuejs-templates

But you don't need to be using .vue files, you can easily leverage components without the single file stuff: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: I think the allure of using the single-file stuff is that it makes for nice encapsulation while being pretty readable.  I have a bunch of 'tiles' I would like to write using Vue.js as single-file components, which then could be placed into multiple razor views when appropriate.  -  I don't know anything about webpack but I'm going to try going down that road to see how difficult it would be within my current environmental constraints...

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone finds this helpful, I went down the rabbit hole and got webpack installed and working with my ASP.NET project (i.e. Orchard module) and VS2017.  Here is a brief summary of the steps I followed, I make no representation this is the *"right"* way to do it, but it worked for me. - I welcome all feedback, as I am just learning these technologies.

1. Download and Install Node.js *(I used the 64 bit installer on windows 10, version 8.11.3 at the time of this writing)*
2. Open a command prompt and cd to the folder containing my *.csproj
3. Create default package.json:

   > npm init -y
4. Install Webpack:

   > npm install webpack --save-dev
5. Install Webpack-cli (note, this might need the --save-dev, not sure anymore)

   > npm install -D webpack-cli
6. Modify your package.json file and add a script for webpack:

   ```
    "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "wbp" : "webpack"
    },
   ```
7. Add webpack.config.js with the following:

   ```
   const path = require('path')
   const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

   module.exports = {

       mode: 'development',

       entry: {
           FirstEntry: './Views/Whatever/Index.js',
           SecondEntry: './Views/YupYup/Foobar.js,
           /* rinse and repeat */
           },

           output: {
               path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
               filename: '[name].js'
           },

       module: {
           rules: [
               {
                   test: /\.vue$/,
                   loader: 'vue-loader'
               },
               // this will apply to both plain `.js` files
               // AND `<script>` blocks in `.vue` files
               {
                   test: /\.js$/,
                   loader: 'babel-loader'
               },
               // this will apply to both plain `.css` files
               // AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
               {
                   test: /\.css$/,
                   use: [
                       'vue-style-loader',
                       'css-loader'
                   ]
               }
           ]
       },

       plugins: [
           // make sure to include the plugin for the magic
           new VueLoaderPlugin()
       ]

   }
   ```
8. Install webpack loaders and peer dependencies

   > npm install babel-core --save-dev
   >
   > npm install "babel-loader" --save-dev
   >
   > npm install "babel-preset-env" --save-dev
   >
   > npm install "css-loader" --save-dev
   >
   > npm install "vue-loader" --save-dev
   >
   > npm install "vue-style-loader" --save-dev
   >
   > npm install "vue-template-compiler" --save-dev

Your package.json devDependencies should now look similar to this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.2.6",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.16.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
}
```

9. Add a pre-build step to your Visual Studio project

   > npm run wbp

10 (Optional) Install **Vue.js Pack 2017** extension for VS2017

[Vue.js Pack 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.VuejsPack-18329)

It took some trial and error, some googling and a lot of reading to get this far.  Again, I am not certain this is the approved *right* way, but hopefully this helps someone.  Cheers!

Comment: You left off a single quote after foobar.js. Thanks for sharing your work!

Comment: Also you need npm install "vue" --save-dev.